# "When do I?" vs. "At what time should I?"

Tags: word-usage

> **When do I** have to come to the office tomorrow?

or

> **At what time should I** come to the office tomorrow?

Are both of them correct? If so, do both of them mean the same? Which one can be used in a formal conversation?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @BenK this was an older question I edited the title of. It was -2 and I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. They do not mean exactly the same thing though. "When" is a more broad term. The answer to the first sentence could be any time expression, such as "later", "during the evening"... Meanwhile, the second question is looking for a more narrow answer (you can't respond with "at winter". An exact time is expected as a response, e.g. "at 12 pm", "at 1 am"...)

The second option is perhaps better to use in a formal conversation, because you are likely to be expected to come to office at some precise time.